# What's causing the difference in file size and structure when compressing through powershell vs compressing manually

Tags: powershell

When I compress a directory in PowerShell, the result is different than when I compress the folder manually by right clicking on the folder and selecting *Winzip → Add to zip file*.

Here's the code I am using in PowerShell:

```
Add-Type -Assembly "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem"
[IO.Compression.Zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory("./output/notification_templates", "./output/notification_templates.zip", [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal, $false)
```

I've also tried

```
Compress-Archive -Path ./output/notification_templates -DestinationPath ./output/notification_templates.zip
```

The result looks like this when I hover over the zip file created through PowerShell (file size 23 kB):

```
Files/Folders in Zip file: 32
jcr_root\.content.xml
jcr_root\test_page29082.html.binary
jcr_root\content\.content.xml
jcr_root\content\boink\.content.xml
jcr_root\content\boink\us\.content.xml
jcr_root\content\boink\us\en\.content.xml
jcr_root\content\boink\us\en\pro\.content.xml
jcr_root\content\boink\us\en\pro\notification_templates\.content.xml
jcr_root\content\boink\us\en\pro\notification_templates\email\.content.xml
Not Shown: 23 files/folders
```

When created manually (size: 32 kB):

```
Files/Folders in Zip file: 61
jcr_root/
jcr_root/.content.xml
jcr_root/content/
jcr_root/content/.content.xml
jcr_root/content/boink/
jcr_root/content/boink/content.xml
jcr_root/content/boink/us/.content.xml
jcr_root/content/boink/us/en/
jcr_root/content/boink/us/en/.content.xml
jcr_root/content/boink/us/en/pro/
jcr_root/content/boink/us/en/pro/.content.xml
jcr_root/content/boink/us/en/pro/notification_templates/
Not Shown: 48 files/folders
```

How do I replicate the manual case with PowerShell?

Comment: Winzip is not the same as io.compression.zipfile. I guess they use different defaults for compression levels. etc. I note here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-6 that the default for `-CompressionLevel` is `Optimal`. Maybe try `Fastest` instead and see if you get the same result.

Comment: Compression level is the first thing I'd look at, as Nick already mentioned. On top of that it looks like Winzip creates explicit entries for each directory while the .Net methods don't.